# FileNotFound Exception in gRPC C# 0.13.0 when used for webapplication

Tags: c#, grpc

I updated my gPRC version for the WebApplication from **0.12.0** to **0.13.0** and it started failing to create a `Channel` object. Following is the exception thrown:

[image]

It is trying to locate `grpc_csharp_ext.dll` at `AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Temporary ASP.NET Files\\root\\c8490d1a\\9f150f28\\assembly\\dl3\\5d08d985\\2c1c8757_6474d101\\nativelibs\\windows_x86\\grpc_csharp_ext.dll`. I even stored the DLL in local `bin` folder but that didn't help. This problem does not occur if I create a Console app. I am not sure why it is trying to search the dll at the said location? Does anyone know how to make it work for a web application?

**Edit** This issue is fixed by GRPC Community as per [Link](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/5589). I have also verified the same. Now we need to keep the `grpc_csharp_ext.dll` under `bin\nativelibs\windows_x86\` (for 32 bit dll) and `bin\nativelibs\windows_x64\` (for 64 bit dll)

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net performs [Shadow Copying Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279(v=vs.110).aspx) during dynamic compilation. It copies Grpc.Core.dll but not the folder *nativelibs* that contains the native *grpc_csharp_ext.dll* files.
I have resolved this issue by programmatically coping the *nativelibs* folder.

Invoke the copy method from Application_Start in Global.asax.

```
public class WebApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GrpcInitializer.EnsureGrpcCSharpExtNativeDll();
    }
}
```

Copier:

```
public static class GrpcInitializer
{
    public static void EnsureGrpcCSharpExtNativeDll()
    {
        var grpcCoreAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Grpc.Core.Channel));
        var srcFolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(grpcCoreAssembly.CodeBase).LocalPath);

        CopyGrpcCSharpExtNativeDll(srcFolderPath);
    }

    public static void CopyGrpcCSharpExtNativeDll(string srcFolderPath)
    {
        var grpcCoreAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Grpc.Core.Channel));
        var grpcDllLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(grpcCoreAssembly.Location);
        if (grpcDllLocation == null)
            return;

        var targetFolderPath = Path.Combine(grpcDllLocation, "nativelibs");
        if (Directory.Exists(targetFolderPath))
            return;

        srcFolderPath = Path.Combine(srcFolderPath, "nativelibs");

        DirectoryCopy(srcFolderPath, targetFolderPath, true);
    }

    private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceDirName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(destDirName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(
                $"Directory paths cannot be empty. sourceDirName: {sourceDirName} | destDirName: {destDirName}");
        }

        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
        if (!dir.Exists)
        {
            throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Source directory does not exist or could not be found: " +
                                                 sourceDirName);
        }

        var dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
        if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
        }

        var files = dir.GetFiles();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
            file.CopyTo(temppath, false);
        }

        if (copySubDirs)
        {
            foreach (var subdir in dirs)
            {
                var temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Grpc-Community has fixed it in their Git Repository. Now you just need to store the grpc_csharp_ext.dll under bin\\nativelibs\\windows_x86\\ of that project.

Comment: In which version they have fixed it? I'm using gRPC C# 0.13.0 .

Comment: They are yet to release the new version yet, it's 0.14.0. I have downloaded the Git repository and rebuilt it on my machine.